# Vectorizing a function after group_by() in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, tidyverse, purrr

I was wondering if there is a way for my `identify_outliers()` call to become vectorized?

That is, instead of accepting only one variable like `identify_outliers(Sepal.Length)`, it would handle multiple variables like `identify_outliers(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)`?

Here is my reproducible code:

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  identify_outliers(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of `map` functions :

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

map_df(names(select(iris, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)), ~{
  iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    identify_outliers(all_of(.x))
})

#   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width is.outlier is.extreme
#   <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>     
# 1 virginica           4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 TRUE       FALSE     
# 2 setosa              5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 TRUE       FALSE     
# 3 setosa              4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 TRUE       FALSE     
# 4 virginica           7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 TRUE       FALSE     
# 5 virginica           6           2.2          5           1.5 TRUE       FALSE     
# 6 virginica           7.9         3.8          6.4         2   TRUE       FALSE     
# 7 setosa              4.3         3            1.1         0.1 TRUE       FALSE     
# 8 setosa              4.6         3.6          1           0.2 TRUE       FALSE     
# 9 setosa              4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2 TRUE       FALSE     
#10 setosa              5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4 TRUE       FALSE     
#11 versicolor          5.1         2.5          3           1.1 TRUE       FALSE     
#12 setosa              5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5 TRUE       FALSE     
#13 setosa              5           3.5          1.6         0.6 TRUE       TRUE
```

Similarly, using `imap_dfr` :

```
imap_dfr(select(iris, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), ~{
  iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    identify_outliers(all_of(.y))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(subset(iris, select = Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)), 
   function(x)  do.call(rbind, by(iris, iris["Species"], 
   FUN = function(dat) identify_outliers(dat, x)))))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~
       list(identify_outliers(cur_data(), all_of(cur_column())))), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Species    Sepal.Length     Sepal.Width      Petal.Length     Petal.Width     
  <fct>      <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>          
#1 setosa     <df[,6] [0 × 6]> <tibble [2 × 6]> <tibble [4 × 6]> <tibble [2 × 6]>
#2 versicolor <df[,6] [0 × 6]> <df[,6] [0 × 6]> <tibble [1 × 6]> <df[,6] [0 × 6]>
#3 virginica  <tibble [1 × 6]> <tibble [3 × 6]> <df[,6] [0 × 6]> <df[,6] [0 × 6]>
```